# Explain how many processes created?

Tags: shell, process, find

Could someone answer how many processes are created in each case for the commands below as I dont understand it :

The following three commands have roughly the same effect:

1. `rm $(find . -type f -name '*.o')`
2. `find . -type f -name '*.o' | xargs rm`
3. `find . -type f -name '*.o' -exec rm {} \;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Exactly 2 processes - 1 for `rm`, the other for `find`.
2. 3 or more processes. 1 for `find`, another for `xargs`, and one or more `rm`. `xargs` will read standard input, and if it reads more lines than can be passed as parameters to a program (There is a maximum value named `ARG_MAX`).
3. Many processes, 1 for `find` and another one for each file ending in `.o` for `rm`.

In my opinion, option 2 is the best, because it handles the maximum parameter limit correctly and doesn't spawn too many processes. However, I prefer to use it like this (with GNU find and xargs):

```
find . -type f -name '*.o' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

This terminates each filename with a `\0` instead of a newline, since filenames in UNIX can legally contain newlines. This also handles spaces in filenames (much more common) correctly.

Comment: There us also `find -exec rm \+` which is conceptually like `xargs` but saves one process.

Comment: What about `find . -type f -name '*.o' -delete`? Isn't this better?

Comment: @Jaypal: yes, that does everything in a single process.

Comment: Re. find's `-delete`... It will work, but be sure to read the man page warning before you run it. Here is part of that warning:   ***Warnings:*** *Don't forget that the find command line is evaluated as an expression, so putting* ***-delete*** *first will make  find  try  to  delete everything  below  the starting points you specified.*

Comment: @perer: that's correct, and it's actually true of `-print0` in that version as well.